# Get the output of a command to variable (not working with pipes,..)

Tags: bash, error-handling

I am trying to get the output of a command so i can see if it's an error or not for some reason the output don't want to store in a variable or in a read pipe.

I tried multiple methods but i really ain't able to get that output

```sh
run() {
        runOutput=$(timeout 2 mcrcon -c -H $HOST -P $PORT -p $PASSWORD "$1")
        exit_status=$?
        if [[ $exit_status -eq 124 ]]; then
                #status off, no other data
                exit 1
        fi
}
```

so basiclly if you put an if with runOuput it should go in the if and stop the program but currently it simply does nothing and the command shows after (here i store it in runoutput and here is a screen)

Code to test :

```sh
timeout 2 mcrcon -H $HOST -p $PORT -P $PASSWORD "/players" | read test
echo "test $test testhja"
```

Result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k0Jh.png

I want simply to get the output of that command to a variable

(i use this program to do the rcon https://github.com/IIPoliII/mcrcon)

Comment: `if you put an if with runOuput` - I don't understand your post. Can you include more example of what you mean? You mean, you want to trap stderr of a command, redirect it with stdin `runOutput=$(.... 2>&1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used:

```
mcrcon -H localhost -p minecraftrcon -w 4 'tellraw @a {"text":"'${your_variable}'","color":"green"}'
```